# $\{x\in [a,b] : f(x)<t\}$ is a countable union of closed set

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a sequence $f_n \in C([a,b])$ and $\lim f_n=f$ on $[a,b]$, then for all $t$, $\{x\in [a,b] : f(x)<t\}$ is a countable union of closed set.

My attempt is to show that the limit $f$ is also continuous, then 
$\{ x \in [a,b] : f(x)\leq t-1/n\} $ is closed. And $\{x\in [a,b] : f(x)<t\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{ x \in [a,b] : f(x)\leq t-1/n\} $

Comment: $f$ may not be continuous.

Comment: For example, let $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$ - the pointwise limit is not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \{x \in [a,b] | f(x)<t\}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{p=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{n=p}^{\infty} \{x \in [a,b]| f_n(x) \leq t-\frac{1}{k}\}\right).$$